# VideoView in ListView

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to use the VideoVideo with the ListView as an item. Has anyone done this? Are there any issues I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the VideoVideo with the ListView as an item.

I doubt it. `SurfaceView` -- which `VideoView` uses -- does not behave much like a normal widget. IIRC, you cannot have two `SurfaceView` widgets active at the same time, regardless of what contains them.

Comment: Only wanted the listview to play one VideoView at any given time. So when an item is selected an instance of the VideoView is created and then added to the ListView item that was selected. If a user scrolls the video out of view then the video is stopped and removed. Is this something that could be done?

Comment: @Tsuma-Shifu: You could give a try, though I am dubious about the usability.

Comment: I have added that but the issue is when adapter render the rows the screen go black for a while. I don't get anything to fix this

Answer (score 1):

I've made a test.Videoview can be inserted into a listview, it can work properly.But when i drag the list, the area which the videoview once occupied will get in front of the screen. Andt the screen will get very dirty.